# Compilation error option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99

Tags: gcc, makefile

I start in language C and I try to compile my program but I have this error.

error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode

I would like to include the option `-std=c99` in my Makefile but I do not know where to put it.

```
# Compilatore
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-W -g -Wall $(OPTLEVEL)
BINFOLDER=./bin
SRCFOLDER=./src
OBJFOLDER=./obj

all: test

test: $(OBJFOLDER)/tas-data.o $(OBJFOLDER)/tas-fct.o $(OBJFOLDER)/tas-io.o $(OBJFOLDER)/tas-main.o
    $(CC) -o $(BINFOLDER)/tas-main  $(OBJFOLDER)/tas-data.o $(OBJFOLDER)/tas-fct.o $(OBJFOLDER)/tas-io.o $(OBJFOLDER)/tas-main.o

$(OBJFOLDER)/tas-main.o: $(SRCFOLDER)/tas-main.c $(SRCFOLDER)/tas-io.h  $(SRCFOLDER)/tas-fct.h $(SRCFOLDER)/tas-data.h
    $(CC) -o $(OBJFOLDER)/tas-main.o  -c $(SRCFOLDER)/tas-main.c

$(OBJFOLDER)/tas-data.o: $(SRCFOLDER)/tas-data.c $(SRCFOLDER)/tas-data.h
    $(CC) -o $(OBJFOLDER)/tas-data.o  -c $(SRCFOLDER)/tas-data.c 

$(OBJFOLDER)/tas-fct.o: $(SRCFOLDER)/tas-fct.c $(SRCFOLDER)/tas-fct.h $(SRCFOLDER)/tas-data.h
    $(CC) -o $(OBJFOLDER)/tas-fct.o -c $(SRCFOLDER)/tas-fct.c

$(OBJFOLDER)/tas-io.o: $(SRCFOLDER)/tas-io.c $(SRCFOLDER)/tas-io.h $(SRCFOLDER)/tas-data.h
    $(CC) -o $(OBJFOLDER)/tas-io.o  -c $(SRCFOLDER)/tas-io.c

clean:
    rm -f $(BINFOLDER)/tas-main $(OBJFOLDER)/*.o

cleanall: clean
    rm -rf $(BINFOLDER)/*
```

Comment: `CFLAGS` seems like a good place.

Comment: @Michael except that CFLAGS sits there unused. Need to actually add it to the rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put it in the flags/options which you provide for compilation. As there are other options inserted in `CFLAGS`, you can put this option in `CFLAGS`.

```
CFLAGS=-W -g -std=c99 -Wall $(OPTLEVEL)
```

Use `CFLAGS` in your compilation commands in the Makefile like this:

```
$(CC) $(CFLAGS)-o $(OBJFOLDER)/tas-main.o  -c $(SRCFOLDER)/tas-main.c
```

**EDIT**

You Makefile will have to be modified this way:

```
# Compilatore
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wextra -g -std=c99 -Wall $(OPTLEVEL)
BINFOLDER=./bin
SRCFOLDER=./src
OBJFOLDER=./obj

all: test

test: $(OBJFOLDER)/tas-data.o $(OBJFOLDER)/tas-fct.o $(OBJFOLDER)/tas-io.o $(OBJFOLDER)/tas-main.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(BINFOLDER)/tas-main  $(OBJFOLDER)/tas-data.o $(OBJFOLDER)/tas-fct.o $(OBJFOLDER)/tas-io.o $(OBJFOLDER)/tas-main.o

$(OBJFOLDER)/tas-main.o: $(SRCFOLDER)/tas-main.c $(SRCFOLDER)/tas-io.h  $(SRCFOLDER)/tas-fct.h $(SRCFOLDER)/tas-data.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(OBJFOLDER)/tas-main.o  -c $(SRCFOLDER)/tas-main.c

$(OBJFOLDER)/tas-data.o: $(SRCFOLDER)/tas-data.c $(SRCFOLDER)/tas-data.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(OBJFOLDER)/tas-data.o  -c $(SRCFOLDER)/tas-data.c 

$(OBJFOLDER)/tas-fct.o: $(SRCFOLDER)/tas-fct.c $(SRCFOLDER)/tas-fct.h $(SRCFOLDER)/tas-data.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(OBJFOLDER)/tas-fct.o -c $(SRCFOLDER)/tas-fct.c

$(OBJFOLDER)/tas-io.o: $(SRCFOLDER)/tas-io.c $(SRCFOLDER)/tas-io.h $(SRCFOLDER)/tas-data.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(OBJFOLDER)/tas-io.o  -c $(SRCFOLDER)/tas-io.c

clean:
    rm -f $(BINFOLDER)/tas-main $(OBJFOLDER)/*.o

cleanall: clean
    rm -rf $(BINFOLDER)/*
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have added the option -std=c99 at the good place but I still have the same error

Comment: The comments on your question by Michael and @n.m. are enough to answer your question.

Comment: @Roxanne, you need to add `$(CFLAGS)` to each line where you are using `$CC`. This way these compiler options will be passed to your compiler executable. Please edit your makefile to add `$(CFLAGS)` everywhere you use `$(CC)`. Please check my answer, I have included an example.

Comment: `-W` is deprecated; `-Wextra` is the new version

Comment: I write this to the test line ? : `$(CC) $(CFLAGS)-o $(OBJFOLDER)/test`

Comment: @Roxanne, Yes, not only to the test line but all the lines where `$(CC)` has been used.